# cucumber capybara test highlighting text

Tags: selenium, xpath, web, cucumber, capybara

Im using Cucumber with Capybara and Selenium, I'm trying to write test on a document reader that support functionality such as define and add note after text is highlight. My first thought is find the element using xpath and double click it, xpath I'm using is `page.find(:xpath, "//text()[contains(.,'Monday')]")`, this would select the entire sentence contains Monday, how do I highlight only '`Monday`'? Anyone help would be really appreciate it

My html looks like this:

```
<p>This is test
    <br>
    "Today is Monday"
    <br>
    "Today is Tuesday"
</p>
```

Comment: try `//*[text() = 'Monday']`

Comment: Thank you for replying Bala, this will return the element that contains 'Monday, what if I just want to select 'Monday'?